# Converting MySQL to MSSQL in PHP: unidentified index in session

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm converting my code from PHP, MySQL to sqlsrv, and for some reason my 'cart' is being called as an unidentified index. Any idea why?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index.php?page=cart') {         
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("; 

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { 
        $sql.=$id.","; 
    } 

    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC"; 
    @$query= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); 
    $numrows = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows != 0) {
        ?><h1>Current Order</h1><?php while($row= sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            ?> 
            <p> <?php echo $row['name'] ?> X <b><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']  ?></b></p> 
            <?php      
        } 
        ?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` needed just after `<?php`

Comment: ...and `$_SESSION['cart']` has to be set somewhere (maybe in a preceding request) before it can be read. Wouldn't an existing converter be an option?

Answer (score 1):

Add `session_start()` after `<?php` tag

```
session_start();    

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index.php?page=cart') 
{             
     $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("; 
     foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) 
     { 
            $sql.=$id.","; 
     }
```

It will work for you, also check `isset` over `$_SESSION['cart']` then use the it.

Comment: as this is part of a index.php, my session_start() is already at the top in my header, does this mean i need to add 2 session_start()?

Comment: @C.oast  you have to include your header file in your index file to make session work.

Comment: @C.oast Try what Anant said. Thanks Anant for your comment